# how to reference array for further calculations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a following problem:

```
a = [] #1-D array
b = [] #1-D array
c = [] #1-D array

xo = 0
d= 10
x = xo + d 

move.append(x)
b = 5*2*pow(x,2)
begin.append(b)

c = begin[i] - begin[i-1]
```

I want to calculate c value based off of begin array value. Am I referencing it correctly?

Comment: Correctly in what sense? You don't initialize `i` anywhere that I can see. What's going wrong with how you're doing it now?

Comment: im not initializing i, how to refer two values in an array and calculate?

Comment: Side note: You have no "arrays" here. `[]` makes an empty Python `list`.

Comment: If `c = [1, 2]`, then `c[1] - c[0]` will be `1` (`2-1`).  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You have to initialize `i` at some point. The value inside the `[]` has to be an `int` value. If you make `i` an instance of `int`, then what you have should work.

Comment: sorry, list. I am filling up the list based on the calculations, I want to refer the list b to fill my list c

Comment: If c = [1, 2], then c[1] - c[0] will be 1 (2-1). Yes @Patrick, this is what I want to do, however, my list will be always updating, so how should i write in a code?

Comment: You're going to have to show us more of your code and explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: if b = [20, 16, 78, 84, 3787, 4, 68, 88, 8]; c[0] = b[1] - b[0]; c[1] = b[2] - b[1]; c[2] = b[3] - b[2]; c[3] = b[4]- b[3] and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the list with itself offset by one:

```
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [y-x for x, y in zip(b, b[1:])]
# [1, 1, 1]
```

Be aware that this won't recalculate values if `b` changes.  When you change `b` you should also change `c`, or recalculate `c` before using it.

Comment: b value also changes; c will change depending on b.

Comment: @user10112519 lists don't do that. Unless you're talking about adding listeners to the list, or wrapping it in a custom object. Really though, why do you even need `c`? It's just simple subtraction. Just calculate the value when you need it.